# Jquery: I am using left side panel and on click on the button list i want to change the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, jsp

Jquery: I am using left side panel(angular js) and on click on the button list i want to change the content on the right side which is a div tag without page reload.

```
    <div id="container"></div>
```

I am using 3 jsp pages which should be replaced in the container on the button click.These 3 jsp pages are linked through href.

```
    <a class="click" href="Home" rel="http://localhost:8080/Dummy/Status.jsp">Home</a>
    <a class="click" href="about" rel="http://localhost:8080/Dummy/dummy2.jsp">About</a>
    <a class="click" href="Contact" rel="http://localhost:8080/Dummy/dummy3.html">Contact</a>
```

Problems I am facing:
When it is a simple html

```
   (ex <p>hello world</p>)
```

it loads the content perfectly but when I load my jsp page which is developed using angular js it gives me a **WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once,and the website doesnt respond.**

This is my jquery to load content:

```
     $('.click').click(function(e){

          e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr('rel');
         $.ajax({
                url: targetUrl,
                type: "GET",
                success:function(){


                    $('#container').load(targetUrl);
                    return false;
                },
                error:function (){
                    alert("testing error");
                }
            });
        });
```

My concern: 
Do i need to use ng-route to use this functionality.
Your help will be appreciated.
Please advice.

Comment: Not an answer to this specific question, but you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background